# SBT: Exclude class from Jar

Tags: scala, sbt

I am converting a legacy jar project to SBT and for strange reasons that are not easily solved, this project comes with "**javax/servlet/Servlet.class**" inside it. So I need to somehow exclude this class from the jar file generated by **package-bin**. How do I accomplish this ?. Preferably I would like to exclude using a wildcard (i.e. **javax.***).

The SBT assembly plugin does look like it has features that will do this, but I am worried that relying on **sbt assembly** means that my jar project will not work in a muliti module project (i.e. if I include it as a dependency in a war file then the war projects needs to be told to run **assembly** on the dependent jar project rather than **package-bin** - but I may be mistaken here).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Each task declares the other tasks and settings that it uses.  You can use `inspect` to determine these inputs as described on  [Inspecting Settings](http://www.scala-sbt.org/release/docs/Detailed-Topics/Inspecting-Settings) and in a recent tutorial-style [blog post by John Cheng](http://blog.fisharefriends.us/full-configuration-with-sbt/).

In this case, the relevant task used by `packageBin` is `mappings`.  The `mappings` task collects the files to be included in the jar and maps them to the path in the jar.  Some background is explained on [Mapping Files](http://www.scala-sbt.org/release/docs/Detailed-Topics/Mapping-Files), but the result is that `mappings` produces a value of type `Seq[(File, String)]`.  Here, the File is the input file providing the content and the String is the path in the jar.

So, to modify the mappings for the `packageBin` task, filter out the paths from the default mappings that you don't want to include:

```
mappings in (Compile,packageBin) ~= { (ms: Seq[(File, String)]) =>
  ms filter { case (file, toPath) =>
    toPath != "javax/servlet/Servlet.class"
  }
}
```

`mappings in (Compile,packageBin)` selects the mappings for the main package task (as opposed to test sources or the packageSrc task).

`x ~= f` means "set x to the result of applying function f to the previous value of x".  (See [More About Settings](http://www.scala-sbt.org/release/docs/Getting-Started/More-About-Settings) for details.)

The filter drops all pairs where the path corresponds to the Servlet class.

Comment: this is a far better solution than my own and a fantastic answer as it also managed to clarify a few core SBT concepts along the way.

Comment: Note that ~= is not documented on 0.13 page, explanation exists in 0.12 docs http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.12.4/docs/Getting-Started/More-About-Settings.html

Comment: Syntax for 0.13:
```mappings in (Compile, packageBin) := {
  (mappings in (Compile, packageBin)).value.filter { case (file, toPath) =>
      toPath != "javax/servlet/Servlet.class"
    }
}```

Answer (score 4):

I came up with this solution, it defines a new compile task which depends on the previous compile task (thus effectively allowing me to hook in right after the source is compiled and before it's packaged)

```
def mySettings = {
  // add functionality to the standard compile task 
  inConfig(Compile)(Seq(compile in Compile <<= (target,streams,compile in Compile) map{
    (targetDirectory, taskStream, analysis) =>
      import taskStream.log
      // this runs after compile but before package-bin
      recursiveListFiles(targetDirectory, ".*javax.*".r) foreach { 
        file =>
          log.warn("deleting matched resource: " + file.getAbsolutePath())
          IO.delete(file)
      }
      analysis
    })) ++
    Seq(name := "MyProject", version := "1.0", exportJars := true)
}

def recursiveListFiles(f: File, r: Regex): Array[File] = {
  val these = f.listFiles
  val good = these.filter(f => r.findFirstIn(f.getName).isDefined)
  good ++ these.filter(_.isDirectory).flatMap(recursiveListFiles(_, r))
}
```

Its a little bit more complicated than what I had hoped but it allows me to do all sorts of modifications prior to packaging (in this case searching the target folder deleting all class files that matches a regular expression). Also it accomplished my second goal of sticking with the default SBT lifecycle.