# SBT before/after hooks for a task

Tags: scala, sbt

(reposted from [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/simple-build-tool/XVr_bwOCKkI))

I'm trying to measure/log the running time of a task.

I've looked into "wrapping" a task by adding one task before and one task after but this would not work every time as sbt only guarantees a partial order.

A better wrapping would be something along these lines:

```scala
wrappedTask := {
  startMeasuringTime()
  somehowInvoke(myTaskKey in SomeContext)
  endMeasuringTime()
}
```

What should this "somehowInvoke" be?

Comment: Which version of SBT? SBT has changed quite a lot after version 0.7.x

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Measuring the time taken by a task needs support from the task executor.
As you imply, you cannot do this only by using task primitives.
I've pushed some [sample code](https://github.com/harrah/xsbt/tree/feature/task_progress) that I wrote a while back that shows the idea.

A complication that the sample code doesn't handle is that what the user conceptually thinks of as one task (compile, for example) may actually be implemented as several tasks and those timings would need to be combined.  Also, a task like `internalDependencyClasspath` "calls" other tasks (flatMap) and so its execution time includes the execution time of the "called" tasks.

EDIT: This was implemented for 0.13.0 as an experimental feature in [602c1759a1885](https://github.com/sbt/sbt/commit/602c1759a18852612488fbed784ddda0e9d3dda3) and [1cc2f57e158389759](https://github.com/sbt/sbt/commit/1cc2f57e158389759c77c62bacade638d83ec12c).  The ExecuteProgress interface provides sufficient information that the previously described issues are not a problem.

Comment: Thanks! As I only needed to measure the time of a run, I ended up making a task that wraps a ScalaRun run.

Comment: The ExecuteProgress looks neat. Is it possible to specify one from "outside" of sbt?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by outside.  Although not implemented, you'd possibly configure it like you would `parallelExecution` or now in 0.12, `concurrentRestrictions`.

Comment: Stil learning sbt's implementation... So, this would mean making a key for it and modify `EvaluateTask` to `def progress: ExecuteProgress[Unit, Task] = getSetting(Keys.executeProgress, new ExecuteProgress [...] )`?