# Print SBT task names as they are start and finish

Tags: scala, sbt

Can SBT be made to output (to the console) the name of each task as it starts and completes - including tasks invoked implicitly as dependencies of other tasks?

I'd like to be able to prefix this output with the system time (using awk) for profiling purposes.

Comment: I didn't immediately see the solution to your problem, but the [Configure and use logging](http://www.scala-sbt.org/release/docs/Howto/logging.html) section of the sbt documentation should get you headed in the right direction.

Comment: Same underlying problem (timing tasks) as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12360974/sbt-before-after-hooks-for-a-task.