# Sbt plugin run tasks before / after an other task

Tags: scala, sbt

I know, I saw [Run custom task automatically before/after standard task](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7820939/run-custom-task-automatically-before-after-standard-task) but it seems outdated. I also found [SBT before/after hooks for a task](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12360974/sbt-before-after-hooks-for-a-task) but it does not have any code example.

I am on `SBT 0.13.17`.

So I want to run my task `MyBeforeTask` and `MyAfterTask` automatically after an other tasks, says `Compile`.

So when you do `sbt compile` I would like to see:

```
...log...
This is my before test text
...compile log...
This is my after test text
```

So I would need to have:

```
object MyPlugin extends AutoPlugin {
  object autoImport {
     val MyBeforeTask = taskKey[Unit]("desc...")
     val MyAfterTask = taskKey[Unit]("desc...")
  }

  import autoImport._

  override def projectSettings: Seq[Def.Setting[_]] = {
     MyBeforeTask := {
       println("This is my before test text")
     },
     MyAfterTask := {
       println("This is my after test text")
     }
  }
}
```

So I think I need things like `dependsOn` and `in` but I am not sure how to set them up.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is not possible to configure for a particular task to run *after* the given task, because that's not how the task dependencies model works - when you specify the task, its dependencies and itself will be executed, but there is no way to define an "after" dependency. However, you can simulate that with dynamic tasks.

To run some task before another, you can use `dependsOn`:

```
compile in Compile := (compile in Compile).dependsOn(myBeforeTask).value
```

This establishes a dependency between two tasks, which ensures that `myBeforeTask` will be run before `compile in Compile`.

---

Note that there is a more generic way to make multiple tasks run one after another:

```
aggregateTask := Def.sequential(task1, task2, task3, task4).value
```

`Def.sequential` relies on the dynamic tasks machinery, which sets up dependencies between tasks at runtime. However, there are some limitations to this mechanism, in particular, you cannot reference the task being defined in the list of tasks to execute, so you can't use `Def.sequential` to augment existing tasks:

```
compile in Compile := Def.sequential(myBeforeTask, compile in Compile).value
```

This definition will fail at runtime with a strange error message which basically means that you have a loop in your task dependencies graph. However, for some use cases it is extremely useful.

---

To run some task *after* another, however, you have to resort to defining a dynamic task dependency using `Def.taskDyn`:

```
compile in Compile := Def.taskDyn {
  val result = (compile in Compile).value
  Def.task {
    val _ = myAfterTask.value
    result
  }
}.value
```

`Def.taskDyn` accepts a block which must return a `Def.Initialize[Task[T]]`, which will be used to instantiate a task to be run later, after the main body of `Def.taskDyn` completes. This allows one to compute tasks dynamically, and establish dependencies between tasks at runtime. As I said above, however, this can result in very strange errors happening at runtime, which are usually caused by loops in the dependency graph.

Therefore, the full example, with both "before" and "after" tasks, would look like this:

```
compile in Compile := Def.taskDyn {
  val result = (compile in Compile).value
  Def.task {
    val _ = myAfterTask.value
    result
  }
}.dependsOn(myBeforeTask).value
```

Comment: What about doing something like `compile in Compile := {val r = (compile in Compile).value ; /* run after? */ ; r } ` ? Sorry can't really do multi line in comments :/

Comment: @Wonay, yes, indeed, this would work - it would run the original compile task before your code. This won't allow you to express your "run after" task as a real task though. That being said, maybe you can simulate that with careful `Def.taskDyn` application, with all potential issues dynamic tasks introduce.