# Improving productivity with Scala test cycle

Tags: scala, scalatest, specs2

It would be great to improve test driven development productivity by automatically firing of tests whenever there is a code change.

This is what I'm hoping for.

1. Whenever a Scala file is saved, SBT (or a shell script) should execute the ScalaTest or Specs2 specifications.
2. If the tests complete, the system should play a sound indicating success or failure

I'm using Scala IDE to do development and SBT to run my test specs at the moment, so just autimating the steps above would save a person from switching to the console, running the test specs and waiting for the result.

Any ideas automatically firing of the tests and playing a 'succeed' or 'fail' sound would be great.

Comment: In sbt, if you run `~test-quick`, it will rerun tests, that call the changed code and dependencies, or failed during the last run. More info: http://twitter.github.io/scala_school/sbt.html

Comment: Now how did I miss that!? Thanks @folone. That already helps a LOT!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not create a custom SBT task that depends on the `test` task. You could add the code for playing the sound to your build definition.

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7820939/run-custom-task-automatically-before-after-standard-task) how to run a custom task after another task.

To automatically re-run tests, simply prefix the newly define task with a `~` in the SBT shell before running it.

Comment: This did the trick thanks. Currently I'm trying to find out how to play a sound if the tests fail (http://stackoverflow.com/q/16057378/828757) The fun never ends ;-)