# Executing a task dependency for test failure in SBT

Tags: scala, sbt

The following piece of code, which resides in my build.sbt, executes if my tests complete successfully. It plays a nice little tune to tell me that my tests completed successfully, freeing me from staring the terminal down like Dirty Harry.

```
test <<= (test in Test) map { result =>
  import java.io.File
  import javax.sound.sampled._
  val clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
  val soundfile = new File("success.wav")
  val inputStream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(soundfile);
  clip.open(inputStream);
  clip.start();
  result
}
```

So I start my tests with ~test and off it goes. Every-time I hit save in the editor, the tests auto-magically re-runs and if they pass, you here the jingle.

*Question is*: how can I go about playing a sound if the tests fail? Currently it just keeps quiet on failure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [Handling Failure](http://www.scala-sbt.org/release/docs/Detailed-Topics/Tasks#handling-failure).  For example,

```
... test in Test mapR {
  case Inc(inc: Incomplete) =>
     ... play failure sound ...
     throw inc
  case Value(v) =>
     ... play success sound ...
     v
}
```