# Run start script generation from SBT task

Tags: scala, sbt

I have this in my `build.sbt` :

```
Seq(SbtStartScript.startScriptForClassesSettings:_*)
```

and then I can generate start script with `sbt start-script`. How can I generate start script in a task, e.g. how to add start script generation after cleaning/compiling to this:

```
val recompile = taskKey[Unit]("Recompile")
recompile := {
  clean.value
  compile.value
}
```

Comment: Question is not clear. What do you want to achieve?

Comment: I want to generate start script over classes compiled after compile.value. Well, there's startScriptForClassesTask() function, but it has a lot of parameters and so usage of it is unclear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the source at [GitHub for sbt-start-script, line 35](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-start-script/blob/master/src/main/scala/com/typesafe/sbt/SbtStartScript.scala#L35), `sbt-start-script` is just a regular task.

So, what prevents you from doing :

```
val recompile = taskKey[Unit]("Recompile")
recompile := {
  clean.value
  compile.value
  startScriptForClasses.value
}
```

Take care, that all these tasks are run in parallel. (see http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/sbt-0.13-Tech-Previews.html#Sequential+tasks for details)

E.g. if you use SBT >= 0.13.8. you can use

```
recompile := Def.sequential(clean in Compile, compile in Compile, startScriptForClasses).value
```

Otherwise, if SBT <= 0.13.7, use the sbt-sequential plugin ( https://github.com/sbt/sbt-sequential )

### Alternative

Also see [Run custom task automatically before/after standard task](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7820939/run-custom-task-automatically-before-after-standard-task?answertab=active#tab-top)