# How add custom target subdirectories to build.sbt?

Tags: sbt

Is there a way to have build.sbt configured so that (additional) specified subdirectories are created if they do not already exist?

I would like build.sbt to create: `./target/test-temp`, and `./target/test-log`.

For example, I intend to have `logback-test.xml` configured to log to `./target/test-log/output.log`.  As far as I can tell, this will make it easier to write tests on the log output itself.

Comment: One [possible solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7821959/6296589).