# How to run a custom Task before SBT's `publish` task in an AutoPlugin?

Tags: scala, sbt

I have a task called `prePublishCheck` which ensures that the Git working tree isn't dirty before publishing a JAR to Artifactory, which is supposed to run before the `publish` task in an AutoPlugin.

How can I get SBT to run this task before `publish`?

The following code has no effect with at least `sbt 1.1.5`:

```
// Has no effect on `publish`
prePublishCheck := { throw new Exception("test") },
publish := (prePublishCheck before publish).value

// Has no effect on `publish`
prePublishCheck := { throw new Exception("test") },
prePublishCheck := (prePublishCheck before publish).value
```

These similar answers are obsolete:

- [Run custom task automatically before/after standard task](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7821959/14193)

Comment: `dependsOn` is not obsolete. have you tried to use it?

Comment: You might want to look at the [_SBT Release_](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-release) plugin, which does something similar to what you want—and a whole lot more—and which also allows customization of the release process.

Comment: @laughedelic How would you use `dependsOn` for the `publish` task? I couldn't find any examples to make it work.

Comment: You can write something like `publish := publish.dependsOn(prePublishCheck).value`