# How to ignore some classes during scala compilation

Tags: scala, class, compilation, sbt

I am running `sbt` in my console where i can enter commands `compile` `run` `test` ...
But as a default these commands always compile every single class they see in your project. The thing is sometimes you want just to `ignore` certain classes because you know they contain errors and don't want to focus on that now.
How do i specify what class(es) i want to be part of the compilation process when i enter one of these commands so that i don't see the unuseful errors from other classes every time?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7819066/sbt-exclude-class-from-jar

Comment: Using an IDE solves this issue at least for writing code.

If you want to compile/run/test in sbt, I don't think that's possible, because the compiler needs eg. the types of certain methods/classes in order to compile others. Therefore, it will have to look at all the files and determine which ones to compile in which order. Since this happens on a module-level afaik, you could split your code into modules -- however the modules you depend on still need to compile before yours can compile (although this might change with build pipelining).

Comment: I know what you're saying. But i mean even if the modules aren't related at all (completely independant) the compiler still compiles everything.

Comment: Assuming you're talking about very few classes then just commenting entire code in those files would do the trick? IntelliJ or VS Code would let you do that with a single keyboard shortcut.