# How to exclude classes from compiling when using executing sbt docker:publishLocal?

Tags: scala, docker, sbt, grpc

My `build.sbt` file has some configuration to use `AkkaGrpcPlugin` and `DockerPlugin` because I am publishing the image at docker hub.

```
lazy val akkaGrpcVersion = "1.0.2"
lazy val protobufVersion = "3.11.4"

enablePlugins(JavaAppPackaging, JavaServerAppPackaging, AkkaGrpcPlugin, DockerPlugin)

akkaGrpcGeneratedLanguages := Seq(AkkaGrpc.Java)
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
......
)
dockerUsername := Some("felipeogutierrez")
```

The `sbt compile` and `sbt run` work just fine, but the command `sbt docker:publishLocal` is not working because it tries to find some classes created by the gRPC in the `target` directory.

```
[error] /home/felipe/workspace-idea/explore-akka/target/scala-2.12/
akka-grpc/main/org/github/felipegutierrez/explore/akka/rpc/greeting/HelloRequest.java:29:7: 
not found: type UnusedPrivateParameter
[error]       UnusedPrivateParameter unused) {
[error]       ^
```

these classes belong to the classes at `package org.github.felipegutierrez.explore.akka.rpc.greeting` and I would like to exclude them from the docker image when I am running `sbt docker:publishLocal`. I tried this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7819066/2096986) but it didn't work. Or find some solution to make this work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I generated the Java files using `AkkaGrpcPlugin` and they were placed on the `target` directory of my project. So the docker compiler could not see it. I removed the `AkkaGrpcPlugin` and the `akkaGrpcGeneratedLanguages := Seq(AkkaGrpc.Java)` from the `build.sbt` and installed the protobuf compiler to generate the Java files by myself.

```
sudo apt install protobuf-compiler
protoc --java_out=main/java main/protobuf/helloworld.proto
```

Then the files are now generated on the `src` directory and Docker can see them. So, I don't have to exclude the files anymore in the `build.sbt`.